# How to remove part of the url ratther than the shop url from the currently fetched web page url

Tags: php, prestashop

In my prestashop shop i have fetched the current web page url by using the below php code.

```
<?php
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $url;
?>
```

My current echo url is http://shoppingworld.com/int/Mens-Tshirts/Fashion.html

My shop url is http://shoppingworld.com/int/

I  need to remove the url portion which is coming next to the above shop url.

Comment: Can you clarify what you have and what you want to have? Or what else you have tried to accomplish your goal?

Comment: The shop url which i have mention belongs to one of the shop in my prestashop group(multishop). For this shop alone i need to perform some update using if condition. @Bryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly get that partial url.

Try this,

```
$url = 'http://shoppingworld.com/int/Mens-Tshirts/Fashion.html';

$parsed = parse_url($url);

$path_array = explode('/', $parsed['path']);

echo $parsed['scheme'] . '//' . $parsed['host'] .'/'. $path_array[1] . '/';
```

**[Demo](https://ideone.com/ykWMD3)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php  

    $url_path="http://www.shoppingworld.com/int/Mens-Tshirts/Fashion.html";

    $a = parse_url($url_path, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
    $b = parse_url($url_path, PHP_URL_HOST);

    $url_name_parse=explode('/',$url_path);
    $url_name=$url_name_parse[3];

    echo ($a . "://" . $b .'/' .$url_name.'/'); ?>
```

Program Output

```
http://www.shoppingworld.com/int/
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/164112)

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr_url = parse_url($url);
$host = $arr_url['host'];
$service_uri = $arr_url['path'];
```

read more in php manual about parse_url();

Comment: There is no `query` string here.